# Parse JSON from URL and skip first line with Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing, web-scraping

I have a URL which contains some JSON data. I would like to parse this data and convert to a dictionary using Python. The first line of the data on the webpage is not in JSON format, so I would like to skip the first line before parsing. The data on the webpage looks like the following:

```
expected 1 issue, got 1
{
  "Issues": [
    {
      "issue": {
        "assignedTo": {
          "iD": "2",
        },
        "count": "1117",
        "logger": "errors",
        "metadata": {
          "function": "_execute",
          "type": "IntegrityError",
          "value": "duplicate key value violates unique constraint \nDETAIL:  Key (id, date, reference)=(17, 2020-08-03, ZER) already exists.\n"
        },
        "stats": {},
        "status": "unresolved",
        "type": "error"
      },
      "Events": [
        {
          "message": "Unable to record details",
          "tags": {
            "environment": "worker",
            "handled": "yes",
            "level": "error",
            "logger": "errors",
            "mechanism": "logging",
          },
          "Messages": null,
          "Stacktraces": null,
          "Exceptions": null,
          "Requests": null,
          "Templates": null,
          "Users": null,
          "Breadcrumbs": null,
          "Context": null
        },
      ],
      "fetch_time": "2020-07-20"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have tried running this script:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("[my_url_here]") as url:
    if(url.getcode()==200):
        for _ in range(1):
            next(url)
        data = url.read()
        json=json.loads(data)
    else:
        print("Error receiving data", url.getcode())
```

But am met with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File 
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I get the same error when I run it without using

```
        for _ in range(2):
            next(url)
```

... but with the last line as 'Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)'.

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: It looks like the object you have is not a valid JSON. Fix this first.

Comment: @baduker could you be a little more specific?

Comment: If more than one issue is "expected" and/or "got", will the rest of the data still be a single JSON object? Or will there be multiple separate pieces of JSON?

Comment: Did you try to verify what the `data` is that you get before the `json.loads` call?

Answer (score 2):

You can Remove the First line by the following code.

> Code:

```
data = ''.join(data.split('\n')[1:])
print(data)
```

> Output:

```
{  "Issues": [    {      "issue": {        "assignedTo": {          "iD": "2",          "name": "industry"        },        "count": "1117",        "logger": "errors",        "metadata": {          "function": "_execute",          "type": "IntegrityError",          "value": "duplicate key value violates unique constraint DETAIL:  Key (id, date, reference)=(17, 2020-08-03, ZER) already exists."        },        "stats": {},        "status": "unresolved",        "type": "error"      },      "Events": [        {          "message": "Unable to record contract details",          "tags": {            "environment": "worker",            "handled": "yes",            "level": "error",            "logger": "errors",            "mechanism": "logging",          },          "Messages": null,          "Stacktraces": null,          "Exceptions": null,          "Requests": null,          "Templates": null,          "Users": null,          "Breadcrumbs": null,          "Context": null        },      ],      "fetch_time": "2020-07-20"    }  ]}
```

As you can see that the we achieved removing first line. But your Parsed Json response have issues. It is not properly formatted. Take a look on the below image.
[image]

On the crossed lines we got extra comma letting know the parser there are more instances left still but your response doesn't have any more instance on that scope. So please check your code which used to convert your data to json. If you have doubt please write here. For validating your json you can check on https://jsonlint.com/

I hope it would be helpful... :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error with the JSON object! However your split code gives an error of 'a bytes-like object is required, not 'str''

Comment: statsjohn123 is it a dictionary object or string object?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to load the json like this:

```
json.loads(data.split("\n",1)[1])
```

this will split the string at the first endline and use the second part of it.
However I discourage this as you can't be sure your server will always reply like this - try to fix the endpoint or find one that returns a valid json reply if you can.

you will still get a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 14 column 68 (char 336)` because of that `\n` in the data.